# Why didn't the producers offer Ridley Scott the chance to direct the 2nd Alien movie?

Tags: production, directors, alien, aliens

*Alien* (1979) was directed by Ridley Scott, but after that in 1986 *Aliens* was written and directed by James Cameron.

Why didn't the studio offer Ridley Scott the chance to direct the 2nd Alien movie?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From [alienseries](https://alienseries.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/ridley-scotts-alien-ii-or-what-he-wanted-to-happen/), the producer blamed it on availability:

> In 1986 Bobbie Wygant asked Aliens producer Gale Anne Hurd if Scott had turned down the opportunity to direct the sequel. “I’m not really sure,” Hurd answered. “I know that he was in post-production on Legend at the time we were in pre-production [on Aliens], so perhaps it was a result of his availability.”

But that wasn't true:

> “They didn’t ask me!” he told The Hollywood Interview in 2008. “To this day I have no idea why. It hurt my feelings, really, because I thought we did quite a good job on the first one.”

There are some rumors circulating around but nothing definitive.

Comment: How does this answer the question? It just confirms that the studio didn't ask Scott.

Comment: @Mouvier It answers the question by confirming that there is no (publicly known) answer.  If Mr. Scott himself doesn't know why, more than 20 years after the movie was released, then it's unlikely any of us ever will.

Comment: They didn't ask Scott because they had reasons to ask Cameron first. They didn't think of Scott at first because they needed a screenplay, and Scott doesn't write.

Comment: Cameron is/was pretty good with white-knuckle action (Terminator), while Scott was better with atmosphere and a bit more of a cerebral take (Alien, Blade Runner). Aliens was definitely more of a popcorn action film, so maybe that had something to do with the choice.

Comment: But that doesn't explain Prometheus and Covenant, which were fully(?) under Scott's command and they are quite the action pieces compared to Alien.

Comment: I'm not going to upvote until this answer explicitly says "nobody knows". At the moment it's just implied.

Comment: @Pharap "There are some rumors circulating around but nothing definitive" seems pretty explicit, to me. And "nobody knows" probably isn't true: surely the people who made the decision know their reasons.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen Prometheus and Covenant _do_ have more action. Prometheus and Covenant are looked upon so badly by many _Alien_ franchise fans that they'll even say _Alien 3_ is a better movie. If that isn't good evidence that Scott should stick to low-action films, I don't know what is.

Comment: Busy schedule was also why he wasn't more involved in Doctor Who. Just designed the daleks and was like "peace!" We should buy him a planner.

Comment: The question is, why did Scott make them action movies, if he doesn't want to do action :)

Comment: How do you know which one is true? Either of them could be wrong or lying.

Comment: @Pharap: then you need to give the producers a Voight-Kampff test

Answer (score 36):

We don't know. Gale Anne Hurd said in 1986

> I’m not really sure. I know that he was in post-production on Legend at the time we were in pre-production [on Aliens], so perhaps it was a result of his availability

Ridley told The Hollywood Interview in 2008

> They didn’t ask me! To this day I have no idea why. It hurt my feelings, really, because I thought we did quite a good job on the first one

There are rumours that Scott have different view on whole Aliens script and with H.R. Giger they envisioned that the second movie would be a prequel telling the story of Space Jockeys and Pyramid.

So maybe there lies an  answer. Producers wanted more alienS while Scott wanted more lore at the cost of not even showing one alien.

Comment: That's so interesting, if the rumours are valid. So, a movie in the spirit of *Prometheus* (2012), rather than what we got in *Aliens* (1986)? Maybe it would have been great, but with how much I adore *Aliens*, my thought is that I'm gladenned by the way history unfolded there.

Comment: @GhotiandChips: I don't have a source in English but I heard that Ridley Scott hates the work of his successors (Cameron, Fincher, Jeunet).

Comment: @Taladris And Stephen King hates *The Shining* film adaptation. If I got dissuaded from enjoying movies because the original authors have reservations, there'd be plenty of masterpieces I'd be depriving myself from.

Comment: @GhotiandChips And Scott isn't even the original author of *Alien*! I should shut my mouth. I'm not much of a fan of Ridley Scott. The only thing he ever did that I loved is *Alien*, and as a director who doesn't write, I don't feel like he deserves as much credit for his work as people like Kubrick or Cameron or Anderson.

Comment: @ToddWilcox You said yourself *the only thing he ever did*, which is the same reason why I refer to him as "the original author", and I mean "author" in the broader, general sense.

Answer (score 24):

1. The heads of Fox (which owned *Alien*) changed between the two movies. The previous heads didn't believe a sequel would be profitable.
2. When Fox's interest in a sequel was reborn, they first needed a script and looked for a writer, and Scott does not write screenplays.
3. Fox development executive Larry Wilson thought Cameron would be good to write the sequel after seeing a copy of his script for *The Terminator*.
4. Following the commercial success of *The Terminator* (which earned about ten times its cost), also written and directed by Cameron, he was asked/offered to direct *Aliens* as well.

Also, Scott's 1982 film *Blade Runner* was not nearly as big a financial success (at the time) as *Alien*, so it's possible that the idea of him directing was not as easy a sell. Scott's 1985 film *Legend* did not make back its investment. Fox execs couldn't have known that when they had to select a director for *Aliens*, but there was likely a feeling that Scott was not on his game in the early 80s.

Scott was working on *Legend* at the time the script for *Aliens* was nearing completion, so Fox execs might have assumed he would decline the offer and there was no point in asking.

From the Wikipedia page on *Aliens*:

> While the producers and development executive Larry Wilson **sought a writer for Alien II**, Wilson came across James Cameron's screenplay for *The Terminator*, and passed the script to Giler, feeling **Cameron was right for the job**. Giler then approached Cameron, who was completing pre-production of *The Terminator*. A fan of the original *Alien*, Cameron was interested in crafting a sequel and entered a self-imposed seclusion to brainstorm a concept for *Alien II*. After four days Cameron produced an initial 45-page treatment, although the Fox management put the film on hiatus, as some disliked the pitch, and they felt that *Alien* had not generated enough profit to warrant a sequel. A scheduling conflict with actor Arnold Schwarzenegger caused filming of *The Terminator* to be delayed by nine months (as Schwarzenegger was filming *Conan the Destroyer*), allowing Cameron additional time to write a script for *Aliens*. While filming *The Terminator*, Cameron wrote 90 pages for *Aliens*, and although the script was not finished, **Fox's new president Larry Gordon was impressed and told him that if *The Terminator* was a success, he would be able to direct *Aliens***.

Comment: This sounds like a good and solid answer and I feel answers the question much better than the other two. However, this desperately needs at least one primary source.